# can one tab "look" at it's nighbor tab and 'read' its data?

Tags: security

I am on Linux. I use Tor mainly to browse on high(er) risk sites, like torrents and such.  Would it be safe to run my gmail account on one tab (of Tor) and on the other tab, to get into a "risky website" that will probably try to implant some Trojans into my computer or just look me out (identify me / my email).

is one tab can "look" at it's nighbor tab and 'read' its data?